# Is the ttl refreshing when I update a document?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I'm using `Azure CosmosDb` to store documents with TTL for documents enabled.

If I upsert an item or replace it, does the TTL count resets and start "counting" from the moment when I update, or it just continues from the "first creation" of the document?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `_ts` parameter in your document, which is the last modified timestamp. And referring to: [Set time to live on an item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-time-to-live#set-time-to-live-on-an-item)

[image]

So, if you update an item or replace it, the TTL count resets and start "counting" from the moment when you modify it.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Then I need to find a way to update also the ttl for the document.